# From timestamp to normal date

Tags: java, android, date

I have `TimeStamp` time as String `1374160160` which is equivalent `07/18/2013`.

If there is a way how I can convert this TimeStamp to date with format `July 18, 2013` ?

This is my code snippet:

```
try{
  String timeStamp = "1374160160";
  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
  return sdf.format(netDate);
} catch(Exception ex) {
  return "";
}
```

It always returns `01/17/1970` why?

The second problem is that `new Date(String)` is deprecated.

To sum up:

How to create normal date (`July 18, 2013`) from time-stamp and avoid the deprecated methods ?

Comment: Should it be `new Date(LONG)` instead of `new Date(STRING)`?

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. All parts of your question have been asked and answered *many* time already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timeStamp` instance holds seconds but `Java` `Date` constructor expects milliseconds. Via [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)):

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

So you should use this:

```
String timeStamp = "1374160160";
long timeMillis = Long.valueOf(timeStamp) * 1000;
Date netDate = new Date(timeMillis);
```

instead of:

```
String timeStamp = "1374160160";
Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
```